# Exclude specific terms from all queries using posts_where or something similar

Tags: wpdb, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Basically what I'm trying to do is exclude all posts that belong to a specific set of terms from showing in any and all queries across the board, EXCEPT when you're actually viewing that post or page. Basically like how YouTube's "unlisted" feature works with videos. I'm wondering what the best way to go about this would be. Below is what I'm using currently, though I feel like this could probably be improved on performance-wise (SQL isn't my strongest suit).

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'exclude_terms_posts_where' );
function exclude_terms_posts_where( $clause = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Returns an array of term IDs to exclude from
    $excluded_terms = get_excluded_terms();

    if ( empty( $excluded_terms ) ) {
        return $clause;
    }

    // Filter out the current page / post
    if ( false !== ( $key = array_search( $post->ID, $excluded_terms ) ) ) {
        unset( $excluded_terms[$key] );
    }

    $excluded_terms = implode( ',', $excluded_terms );
    $clause .= "
        AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID NOT IN (
            SELECT {$wpdb->posts}.ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON (
                {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
            )
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON (
                {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id
                AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'placement'
                AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id IN ( {$excluded_terms} )
            )
        )
    ";

    return $clause;
}
```

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My SQL knowledge is quite bad, I should admit, so I'm going to use a non SQL way to achieve this.

**Here is my idea:**

Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the query variables before the main query is executed. As all of the query variable has been set by the time `pre_get_posts` run, you can simply change them as needed, and also, the conditional tags are available, so you can do what you need conditionally.

For, example, you said you need to exclude a certain term, so you can use a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to exclude the term from the main query, and use [`is_tax`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) to allow that term on the specific taxonomy page

Something like this might work. *Please note: This is untested*

```
function wpse_exclude_term( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_tax( 'TAXONOMY_NAME', 'TERM_NAME/SLUG/ID' ) ) {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'TAXONOMY_NAME',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'TERM_SLUG',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ),
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_exclude_term' );
```

**RUNDOWN ON SOME OF THE IMPORTANT CODE**

- `!is_tax( 'TAXONOMY_NAME', 'TERM_NAME/SLUG/ID' )` Conditional check which check if you are **not** on the specific taxonomy page. Note the NOT operator (`!`)
- `!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()` Basically just make sure that changes are only made in the main query and on the front end
- `'operator' => 'NOT IN'` This excludes the specific term specified in the `tax_query`

Comment: Much cleaner way than using SQL ps: I think one should append this extra tax query.

Comment: I hope I get you here, the `tax_query` can be removed and then you van work directly with the query vars, correct? :-)

Comment: I was just thinking about not overriding the current tax query ;-)

Comment: I'm on my way out now, would be nice to see your approach, so please post your's :-). Will pop back in tomorrow. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Already upvoted your approach, since this is what I would have suggested ;-) Regarding the appending we could get the current taxonomy query array and append the  extra array from your answer to it, and then set it again. Sorry for being unclear describing this ;-)

Comment: Here's the problem with tax_query though. Imagine this scenario:

Plugin / theme creates a WP_Query that includes its own tax_query.

Plugin / theme query is totally broken when its tax_query is replaced.

If we append our tax_query, if plugin / theme uses an 'OR' relationship then our query totally breaks. If they use an 'AND' relationship, their query totally breaks. No obvious explanation why in either case.